# Bigquery code to return results matching two search parameters

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to return results which feature two specific IP addresses, I know if I use the following  "AND ip = " and only enter one address it returns those results. I can also use OR and get results which feature either of the two addresses. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to only return results which feature both IP addresses. Any ideas?

Tried "AND ip = ", "AND ip = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx AND xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.", "AND ip = (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

Comment: You'll want to either use an `IN` (preferred) or an `OR` not an `AND`.  For more information on the various operators you can use look here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp .  The reason the `AND` does not work is because you are saying both statements must be true for each row which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks I've tried that and it works to an extent, ideally I would only want results that match both IP addresses e.g. entity A has been recorded with both 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2, is it possible to do this?

Comment: It likely is, but if you could provide example inputs and expected output that would be helpful in determining the solution.